# Scope of variables in case of modules used by modules in Fortran

Tags: module, include, fortran, fortran90

I've noticed that variables in a (child) module, which are used by a parent modules are accessible in a main program through just the parent module. This is one concept which clearly distinguishes `use` statement in Fortran from `include` statement in C/C++. The following programs clearly illustrate this concept.

**a.f90**

```
module a_mod
 use b_mod
 implicit none

 integer :: a
end module
```

**b.f90**

```
module b_mod
  use c_mod
  implicit none

  integer :: b

end module
```

**c.f90**

```
module c_mod
  implicit none

  integer :: c = 10

contains

  subroutine inc_c
    c = c + 10
  end subroutine inc_c
end module
```

**test.f90**

```
program test
  use a_mod
  implicit none

  call inc_c
  write(*,*),c
end program
```

Note that I am able to call a function in `c_mod` by just using `a_mod`. Note that I cannot directly observe that `c_mod` is available unless I traverse the dependency list.

But in a complicated software, is there a simple way to know (say, using an IDE) if a variable is available for use at a particular line?

Comment: Every IDE is different. This cannot be really answered. Some IDE may offer this feature and other may not.  Many Fortran programmers don't use any IDE at all.

Comment: Note that Fortran has finer Fortran of accessibility using `private`, `public` and `only`.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do, in my opinion, is to avoid the use of blanket `use` statements, especially for large and sometimes unwieldy modules. Instead, specify which module entities to inherit via the `only` keyword, such as:

```
program main
   use a_mod, only : c, inc_c
   implicit none

   call inc_c
   write(*,*) c
end program main
```

This works, but it's confusing because `a_mod` isn't the real owner of `c` and `inc_c`. Therefore, you should try to `use` entities from where they are actually declared, which gives:

```
program main
   use c_mod, only : c, inc_c
   !   ^ This has changed
   implicit none

   call inc_c
   write(*,*) c
end program main
```

Now, anybody reading the code has a clear notion of which variables and subroutines are in scope and where they come from.

Finally, this has the added benefit of reducing the risk that you use `c` without realizing it's actually inhereted from `c_mod`. This is particularly a problem when not using `implicit none`!

Answer (score 2):

As Vladimir F suggested in a comment, you can solve this issue using `private` and `public` statements in your modules. If you rewrite your modules like this:

```
module a_mod
  use :: b_mod

  private
  public :: a

  integer :: a
end module

module b_mod
  use :: c_mod

  private
  public :: b

  integer :: b
end module

module c_mod
  private
  public :: c, inc_c

  integer :: c = 10
contains
  subroutine inc_c
    c = c + 10
  end subroutine
end module
```

In this case, the statement `private` in the beginning of each module means that quantities declared in the module are *not* exported by default. You now have to explicitly declare what variables and subroutines to make available when you `use` the module by adding a `public` statement. (This could alternatively be done in one line using the syntax `integer, public :: c = 10`.) This practice prevents `c_mod` variables from leaking out of `b_mod`, and so on.

Comment: I don't think this effectively solves the problem. The point is to use `c` and `inc_c` from `c_mod` in `b_mod`. Making the entities private prevents that.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you make the entries private everywhere. I'm suggesting that you make them `public` in `c_mod` (so that they *are* imported when you `use :: c_mod`), but make the same variables `private` in `b_mod` (so that they are *not* imported when you `use :: b_mod` or `use :: a_mod`). This, I believe, does solve the problem.

Comment: Note that I in my version of `c_mod` explicitly say `public :: c, inc_c`, while your comment indicates that you thought I set these to `private` instead.

Comment: I see now, you're right that this addresses the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Though not inituitve like IDE, gfortran can print a list of imported symbols by attaching the `-fdump-fortran-original` (or `-fdump-parse-tree`) option. To do so, we first generate *.mod file as

```
gfortran -c {c,b,a}.f90
```

and compile the desired source as

```
gfortran -fdump-fortran-original -c test.f90
```

Then, we get a list of imported symbols like this:

```
Namespace: A-Z: (UNKNOWN 0)
procedure name = test
  symtree: 'a'           || symbol: 'a'            
    type spec : (INTEGER 4)
    attributes: (VARIABLE IMPLICIT-SAVE USE-ASSOC(a_mod))
  symtree: 'a_mod'       || symbol: 'a_mod'        
    type spec : (UNKNOWN 0)
    attributes: (MODULE  USE-ASSOC(a_mod))
  symtree: 'b'           || symbol: 'b'            
    type spec : (INTEGER 4)
    attributes: (VARIABLE IMPLICIT-SAVE USE-ASSOC(b_mod))
  symtree: 'b_mod'       || symbol: 'b_mod'        
    type spec : (UNKNOWN 0)
    attributes: (MODULE  USE-ASSOC(b_mod))
  symtree: 'c'           || symbol: 'c'            
    type spec : (INTEGER 4)
    attributes: (VARIABLE IMPLICIT-SAVE USE-ASSOC(c_mod))
  symtree: 'c_mod'       || symbol: 'c_mod'        
    type spec : (UNKNOWN 0)
    attributes: (MODULE  USE-ASSOC(c_mod))
  symtree: 'inc_c'       || symbol: 'inc_c'                             <---        
    type spec : (UNKNOWN 0)                                             <---
    attributes: (PROCEDURE MODULE-PROC  USE-ASSOC(c_mod) SUBROUTINE)    <---
  symtree: 'test'        || symbol: 'test'         
    type spec : (UNKNOWN 0)
    attributes: (PROGRAM PUBLIC  SUBROUTINE)
```

(For example, the lines with arrow indicates that a routine `inc_c` is available from `c_mod`.) If we modify test.f90 so as to attach the `only` keyword,

```
program test
  use a_mod, only: inc_c
  implicit none

  call inc_c
end program
```

then the output is also simplified accordingly:

```
Namespace: A-Z: (UNKNOWN 0)
procedure name = test
  symtree: 'a_mod'       || symbol: 'a_mod'        
    type spec : (UNKNOWN 0)
    attributes: (MODULE  USE-ASSOC(a_mod))
  symtree: 'inc_c'       || symbol: 'inc_c'        
    type spec : (UNKNOWN 0)
    attributes: (PROCEDURE MODULE-PROC  USE-ASSOC(c_mod) SUBROUTINE)
  symtree: 'test'        || symbol: 'test'         
    type spec : (UNKNOWN 0)
    attributes: (PROGRAM PUBLIC  SUBROUTINE)
```

So, althogh I've never used this option for this purpose, it might be of some use for the OP's purpose (if really necessary).